# Is it possable to make an app

Tags: android

A little background first. I'm a irragator at work and have to write down my water changes on a notebook it would look like this.
            2/15/14
1 on sw 45% 8:15
3 off 8:30
12 on n 35% 8:45
and so on. I would like to make an app that I  could make out my list and head out to do the water changes and their would be two of us doing this. The list would start out like 
1 on
3 off
12 on
AS we do the water change I would like to do the rest with list pickers an
d get a time stamp. Then have it sync between the two of us to have one list. I would like to save the  list until I delete it. Have a new list for the next day. If all this would work I would like to save each field number (1, 2, 3 out to 50) to its own file or excel sheet to bring up 5 years later. So is this possible? It would be on a android phone.
Thanks Stacey

Comment: If you are really interested and willing to put the work in I will help you figure it out in my free time. But you have to be willing to learn it. Or if you have some cash I'll make it for you ;)

Comment: First check whether you can achieve what you want with existing off the shelf apps. Google Docs for Android lets multiple users collaborate on documents and sync between devices, for example.

Answer (score -1):

I think the short answer is "yes."  You'd need a place for the list to be stored, and there would be some significant programming involved, but it can be done.